# Condition in function not producing expected output

Tags: r, function

this is my first post here after being a passive user for a while now.

I recently started learning functions in R and I have a function where I used two ways to solve it.
Here's one that works:

```
    find_longer_vector <- function(a, b) {
    vlength <- case_when(
    length(a) > length(b) ~ "First",
    !(length(a) > length(b)) ~ "Second",
    (length(a) == length(b)) ~ "Equal length"
  )
  return(vlength)
}
```

The first two conditions run but the third doesn't work please help.

The second method I tried ought to work but doesn't return an output at all:

```
find_longer_vector <- function(a, b){
if (length(a) > length(b)) {
  vlength <- "First"
} else if(!(length(a) > length(b))){vlength <- 'Second'
} else if(length(a) == length(b)){
  vlength <- 'Equal'
  
  return(vlength)
}}
```

It'd be awesome to get some help on this.

Comment: Don't add irrelevant tags (python here) please

Comment: The second condition is not right, not `>` is `<=` so it includes equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`case_when` executes commands in a sequential manner meaning it will first check for condition 1 if it is `TRUE` it will return the corresponding output and not check other conditions. If it is `FALSE` it will go for condition 2.

The third one does not work because before reaching to the third condition the second condition (`!(length(a) > length(b))`) becomes `TRUE` hence it returns that value. Place the equal condition first.

```
find_longer_vector <- function(a, b) {
  vlength <- dplyr::case_when(
    length(a) == length(b) ~ "Equal length",
    length(a) > length(b) ~ "First",
    TRUE ~ "Second",
  )
  return(vlength)
}

find_longer_vector(1:10, 1:10)
#[1] "Equal length"
find_longer_vector(1:10, 1:15)
#[1] "Second"
find_longer_vector(1:10, 1:5)
#[1] "First"
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak, that definitely worked. Any ideas on the second function?

Comment: @Kamso It is the same logic as the first. Move the `==` condition first and it should work.